# why is parsecs "choice" combinator seemingly stuck on the first choice?

Tags: xml, parsec, haskell

After looking at the CSV sample code in Real World Haskell, I've tried to build a little XML parser. But close tags error out with 'unexpected "/"' errors. Can you tell me why my "closeTag" parser doesn't work (or possibly isn't ever invoked)? Thanks!

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

xmlFile = manyTill line eof
line = manyTill tag eol
eol = char '\n'

word = many1 (noneOf "></")

tag = choice [openTag, closeTag, nullTag, word]

nullTag = between (char '<') (string "/>") word
closeTag = between (string "</") (char '>') word
openTag = between (char '<') (char '>')  tagContent
attrval = between (char '"') (char '"') word

atts = do {
        (char ' ')
        ; sepBy attr (char ' ')
}

attr = do {
                word
                ; char '='
                ; attrval
        }

tagContent = do {
                w <- word
                ; option []  atts
                ; return w
        }

parseXML :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
parseXML input = parse xmlFile "(unknown)" input

main =
    do c <- getContents
       case parse xmlFile "(stdin)" c of
            Left e -> do putStrLn "Error parsing input:"
                         print e
            Right r -> mapM_ print r
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Parsec's strategy is essentially LL(1), which means that it "commits" to the current branch whenever any input is consumed.  Your `openTag` parser consumes the `<` with its `char '<'`, which means that if when it sees `>` instead of `/`, the whole parse fails instead of trying a new choice.  If `openTag` didn't consume any input and failed, another choice would be tried.  Parsec does this for efficiency (the alternative is exponential time!) and for reasonable error messages.

You have two options.  The preferred option, when it is reasonable to pull off, is to factor your grammar so that all choices are made without consuming input, eg.:

```
tag = word <|> (char '<' >> tagbody)
    where
    tagbody = do
        content <- tagcontent
        choice [ string "/>", char '>' ]
```

Modulo errors and style (my brain is a bit fried at the moment :-P).

The other way, which locally changes parsec's semantics (at the expense of the aforementioned error messages and efficiency -- but it's not usually too bad because it's local), is to use the `try` combinator which allows a parser to consume input and still fail "softly" so another choice can be tried:

```
nulltag = try $ between (char '<') (string "/>") word
-- etc.
```

Sometimes using try is cleaner and easier than factoring like above, which can obscure the "deep structure" of the language.  It's a stylistic trade-off.

Comment: Good answer - a further note on `try`. Parsec is perhaps unusual in that it allows you to write lexing functions (Char parsers) using the same code as regular "syntax" parsers. For Char parsers `try` is very valuable; for syntax parsers `try` is problematic and best avoided usually by left-factoring your grammar.

Comment: @stephentetley would you expand upon why `try` is valuable for lexers?

Comment: @StevenShaw, sounds like a new question :-)